# While on call, typing a digit on dial pad doesn't make any sound

Tags: calls

Since my Samsung Duos phone was upgraded to Android 5.0.2, during a call, when I dial some digits on the numeric pad, there is no keypad tone heard. As a consequence, when an answering machine asks my choice like "press one", "press two", I just cannot provide any choice.

I tried pretty much all settings (dialing keypad tone, touch sounds), with no luck, I can't even imagine why disabling this feature.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Device: Samsung Duos  (SM_A300H)  Android version 5.0.2. I don't think it comes from the device, I have it for a year and I have always been able to "press one"  "press two" on request

Comment: #*#0673#*#  leads to msg  "connection problem or invalid MMI code"    there is no menu except the classic 3 vertical points icon below the Contacts icon, with menus "Speed Dial" and "Settings" , that don't offer any untried setting

Comment: On my phone I can't hear the keypad tones at my end, but they still get sent to the other end, so automated menus still work. Have you definitely tried using the answering machine?

Comment: absolutely, it didn't work yesterday but today it worked??!!   I think it is definitely not a good idea to suppress this dial tone for user,   thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is good to know that the problem has been resolved. After my suggestions including "cheat code" did not fix the problem yesterday, I discussed this with a Samsung ROM developer. You may like to consider options based on this discussion.

Firstly, the tones which failed are [DTMF](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual-tone_multi-frequency_signaling) tones. These are NOT

- User configurable
- Affected by app misbehaviour
- Custom ROM developers also do not tinker with this as it is a deep feature and they don't need to tweak it for user benefit
- Stock ROMs/ upgrades will NOT disable it

As to how this happened is a mystery, but there is always an annoying possibility, that this *may* occur again. You have three options

1. **Do nothing:** If it happens again you can try using these kind of apps (bunch of them on Play Store, Google for "DTMF") [DTMF Tone Generator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.amknott.ToneGen)

Any of next two options recommended

- **Device not rooted**

  - Take backup using *Kies*
  - Factory reset
  - Do firmware upgrade/restore using *Kies*
  - Restore data using *Kies*

Or see this for other ways of taking back up  [Full Backup of non-rooted devices](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/28296/full-backup-of-non-rooted-devices)

- **Device rooted**

  - Take  nandroid backup using custom recovery backup
  - Factory reset
  - Flash upgraded Stock ROM

    - Can be downloaded from [Sammobile](http://www.sammobile.com/) after registration. Make sure you download the correct version and of your region
    - Flash stock using Odin
- Restore data from nandroid backuo

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer, yet please say SAMSUNG dev that removing DTMF tone from caller hears is definitely misleading and not a good idea

Comment: Thanks for accepting but to clarify that the person I spoke to is a "Custom ROM developer",  not connected with OEM. It may be better to voice your concern by contacting Samsung help directly and mailing them