# Generating DTMF tones, when dialling a mobile number

Tags: phone-app

Where could I turn on an option, which, when I dial a number, generates DTMF tones? I have full volume, so that is not the problem. Is there an option in settings somewhere? I have a Samsung Galaxy S3. Kitkat version 4.4.2.

Comment: No. DTMF  tones are not user configurable. See [this answer for more details](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/134798/131553)